# sorting in pandas groupby with two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group a dataframe with two columns and avoid default sorting using 'sort = False'. However, I am unable to achieve this.

Here is the simplified example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['zebra', 1, 10],
        ['zebra', 2, 10],
        ['apple', 3, 20],
        ['apple', 4, 20],
    ],
    columns=['ColA','ColB','ColC'])
```

df is therefore

```
    ColA  ColB  ColC
0  zebra     1    10
1  zebra     2    10
2  apple     3    20
3  apple     4    20
```

I am using pandas (1.0.3) groupby and disabling sorting of the keys

```
df_agg = df.groupby(by=['ColA','ColB'], sort = False)

df_agg.groups
```

results in

```
{('apple', 3): Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'),
 ('apple', 4): Int64Index([3], dtype='int64'),
 ('zebra', 1): Int64Index([0], dtype='int64'),
 ('zebra', 2): Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')}
```

which is the same as "sort = True" (default)

However, what I would like is as following

```
{
 ('zebra', 1): Int64Index([0], dtype='int64'),
 ('zebra', 2): Int64Index([1], dtype='int64'),
 ('apple', 3): Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'),
 ('apple', 4): Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')
}
```

'sort = False' when grouping by one column seems to be working fine.

```
df_agg = df.groupby(by=['ColA'], sort = False)
df_agg.groups
```

results in

```
{'zebra': Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
 'apple': Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64')}
```

If sorting only works on one column and not on tuples.  I could sort the groups dict based on the tuple, but I am using an application that is expecting a groupby object. I appreciate any pointers on how this can be addressed.

Comment: Can you not just switch the order of the groupby?  `df.groupby(['ColB', 'ColA']).groups` other wise create a new group sorting psuedokey and group by that key first, then drop that key afterwards.

Comment: @ScottBoston I tried it. it seems to have the same issue. Ideally, I want to keep the order of the colA in df. I didnot try the psuedokey method.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me and this should be reported as a bug on github.

Comment: The `groupby` object's `groups` attribute is a dictionary and not where it sources the order of the groups.  It is only to track what the index values are for each group.  You can't determine whether or not it "worked" from looking at it.

Comment: In other words, it is a mistake to assume that the `groups` attribute should be any different when you use `sort=False`

Comment: @piRSquared thanks. however, if I use one column. and sort =False, then the groups attribute is showing the keys not sorted and viceversa. please see my latest edit.

Comment: @plasmon360 don't draw any conclusions form that.  You are looking at the ordering of dictionary keys.  Dictionaries have previously been non-ordered.  That unorderedness was prevalent when Pandas was first developed and the order of the groups had to be dealt with another way.  Even though Python does now preserve dictionary key order, you should **NOT** depend on this particular dictionary key ordering to represent the order of your groups. Even if it coincidentally looks like it works sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `groups` attribute is a dictionary and **NOT** where order of groups is determined.  You must "resolve" the `groupby` object with some operation to determine what the order is/was.

```
df.groupby(['ColA', 'ColB'], sort=False, as_index=False).first()

    ColA  ColB  ColC
0  zebra     1    10
1  zebra     2    10
2  apple     3    20
3  apple     4    20
```

Versus

```
df.groupby(['ColA', 'ColB'], as_index=False).first()

    ColA  ColB  ColC
0  apple     3    20
1  apple     4    20
2  zebra     1    10
3  zebra     2    10
```

The **ACTUAL** place to look is the `groupby` object's `ngroup` method

```
g1 = df.groupby(['ColA', 'ColB'], sort=False, as_index=False)
g1.ngroup()

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
dtype: int64
```

Versus

```
g2 = df.groupby(['ColA', 'ColB'], as_index=False)
g2.ngroup()

0    2
1    3
2    0
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's use a psuedo sort key, here I create one using `pd.factorize`:

```
df.assign(sortkey=pd.factorize(df['ColA'])[0]).groupby(['sortkey', 'ColA', 'ColB']).groups
```

Output:

```
{(0, 'zebra', 1): Int64Index([0], dtype='int64'),
 (0, 'zebra', 2): Int64Index([1], dtype='int64'),
 (1, 'apple', 3): Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'),
 (1, 'apple', 4): Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')}
```

Comment: can we somehow drop that psuedo key?

Comment: Well, if you were doing something with the smaller groups, sure you can reset_index(level=0, drop=True).